# Regular expression Pattern matching java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need to have a Regex for the string:
`Created ID @DBDOYEF has problems`

The word `@DBDOYEF` may contain `a-z,A-Z,0-9` and all special characters like

```
~!#$%^&*()_+{}:"<>?,./\.
```

Please help me to create a pattern for this word. I used

```
Created ID \\b[A-Z][0-9][\\//+-@#$%^~&*!():]+\\b has problems
```

for this, but it fails for many cases.

Comment: Please give some your testcase...

Comment: Try `Created ID @[A-Za-z0-9~!#$%^&*()_+{}:\"<>?,./]+` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aL9xL1/1)

Comment: it may or may not start with @. some times it starts with : or A-Z or a-z or 0-9.

Comment: Test is
public void testCode(){
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("ID \\b@[A-Za-z0-9~!#$%^&*()_+{}:\"<>?,./]+b is not owned by a Customer");
Matcher match=pattern.matcher("ID @DBDOYEF is not owned by a Customer");
String found=null;
  if (match.find())
  {
   System.out.println("match found at: " +match.group() +" for the string: "+match.group());
   found="found";
   
  }
  else
  {
   found=null;
  }
  assertNotNull(found);
  
 }

Comment: You should edit your question (click on edit below your post) to include this code. It'd be easier to read if you used proper code formatting in the body of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are

- `\b` only matches between a "word character" (letter/digit/underscore) and a non-word character (or start/end of string). You therefore need a different method to determine that your match has ended. Since you already have spaces before and after your identifier, you already have such a method and can remove the `\b`s.
- `-` is a metacharacter in a character class and needs to be placed at the start or end of the character class so it isn't interpreted as a range token (as in `A-Z`).
- Your identifier starts with a `@`, but that isn't part of `[A-Z]`, so that can't match. You probably want to (optionally) start the match with `@`.
- Apparently the identifier doesn't require a number in position 2 and does allow letters after position 1, so you should combine the three character classes into two (assuming that the first letter needs to be a letter or digit).

That gives you

```
Created ID @?[A-Z0-9][-A-Z0-9\\/+@#$%^~&*!():]+ has problems
```

If IDs like `-(X@Q)` are also valid, you can simplify that to

```
Created ID [-A-Z0-9\\/+@#$%^~&*!():]+ has problems
```

Answer (score 0):

> it may or may not start with @. some times it starts with : or A-Z or a-z or 0-9

You were trying `[A-Z][0-9][\\//+-@#$%^~&*!():]+`, which requires **1** letter, followed by **1** digit, followed by any punctuation. Instead, use the same [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for all allowed characters.

**Regex**

```
Created ID [@A-Za-z0-9~!#$%^&*()_+\-{}:\"<>?,./]+
```

- `[@A-Za-z0-9~!#$%^&*()_+\-{}:\"<>?,./]+` Matches any of the characters in the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) any times.

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/aL9xL1/2)</kbd>